# how to inject a service in a thread created through executor service in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, executorservice

I have created a simple service like ... where I have to take some data from database at later

```
package com.spring.scheduler.example.springscheduler;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ExampleService {

    private String serviceName;
    private String repository;

    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }
    public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }
    public String getRepository() {
        return repository;
    }
    public void setRepository(String repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
}
```

Here is my task scheduler created to run different threads.

```
@Component
public class TaskSchedulerService {

    @Autowired 
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler;
     public ScheduledFuture<?> job1;        
     public ScheduledFuture<?> job2;

     @Autowired 
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;


     @PostConstruct
     public void job1() {
         //NewDataCollectionThread thread1 = new NewDataCollectionThread();
         NewDataCollectionThread thread1 = applicationContext.getBean(NewDataCollectionThread.class);
         AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
         factory.autowireBean(thread1);
         factory.initializeBean(thread1, null);
         job1 = threadPoolTaskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(thread1, 1000);
     }

 }
```

This is a thread trying to call from scheduler. I tried to create service instance forcibly by using application context but it's not created.

```
@Configurable
@Scope("prototype")
public class NewDataCollectionThread implements Runnable {

private static final Logger LOGGER = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(NewDataCollectionThread.class);

@Autowired
private ExampleService exampleService;

@Override
public void run() {
    LOGGER.info("Called from thread : NewDataCollectionThread");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " The Task1 
    executed at " + new Date());
    try {
        exampleService.setRepository("sdasdasd");
        System.out.println("Service Name :: " + 
        exampleService.getServiceName());
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

Kindly suggest what are the possible ways to achieve it.

Comment: I have to inject multiple services in a thread at later stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Autowired 
private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

@PostConstruct
public void job1() {
    NewDataCollectionThread thread1 = new NewDataCollectionThread();
    beanFactory.autowireBean(thread1);
    job1 = threadPoolTaskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(thread1, 1000);
}
```

In NewDataCollectionThread I injected the Example service successfully.

Comment: The issue is that by doing `NewDataCollectionThread thread1 = applicationContext.getBean(NewDataCollectionThread.class);` you are requesting the bean to the spring context, since NewDataCollectionThread is not mark as @Component it wont auto inject anything. So you need to instantiate the bean first if you want to do it in runtime and then send it to the context to be autowired